# Android kotlin - registerForActivityResult not working

Tags: android, kotlin

Since `startActivityForResult` is deprecated I try to make the new method work.

This is in activity A:

```
launcher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
    Log.d(tagg, "returned")

    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val data: Intent? = result.data

        if (data != null) {
            if (data.hasExtra("cats")) {
                val cats = data.getStringExtra("cats")
            }
        }
    }
}

chooseCategoryButton.setOnClickListener {
    val i = Intent(this, ChooseCats::class.java)
    launcher.launch(i)
}
```

activity B:

```
val finishIntent = Intent()
finishIntent.putExtra("cats", "blaaaaa")
setResult(RESULT_OK, finishIntent)
```

It just doesn't work! How to do this right?

Comment: Are you creating your launcher inside a method or are you [creating it as a member variable in your class](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#register)?

Comment: What you see in activity A is inside OnCreate

Comment: I also tried to put the launcher outside OnCreate, namely above of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have written is 100% correct. Just make sure

```
override fun onCreate(){
chooseCategoryButton.setOnClickListener {
val i = Intent(this, ChooseCats::class.java)
launcher.launch(i)
}
}

val launcher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
Log.d(tagg, "returned")

if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    val data: Intent? = result.data

    if (data != null) {
        if (data.hasExtra("cats")) {
            val cats = data.getStringExtra("cats")
        }
    }
}
```

}

In activity B add below code inside some onclick or action

```
override fun onClick(view : View) {
when(view.id){
R.id.mbtnClick -> {
val finishIntent = Intent()
finishIntent.putExtra("cats", "blaaaaa")
setResult(RESULT_OK, finishIntent)
   }
  }
}
```